# Open multiple windows using servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have a String Array of URLs coming from a JSP.

Now I want to open each URL in a new tab of the same browser.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String[] urls = request.getParameterValues("URLs");
    String env = request.getParameter("env");
    for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        openInNewTab(urls[i]);
    }
}
```

So how do I write The method openInNewTab(String Url).
I am new to servlets and JSP.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't do that.  Instead, write Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured it out myself

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html><body>");
    out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
    for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
      out.println("window.open(\""+urls[i]+"\");");
    }
    out.println("</script>");
    out.println("</body></html>");
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

Anyways guys thanks for the support

Answer (score 2):

You have a big misunderstanding of what servlet can do. This is a job for the client-side (in javascript), not for the server-side.

Comment: As far as I know we can write HTML from servlet including javascript in that something like

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        out.println("window.open("+ur+")");
        out.println("</script>");
        out.println("</body></html>");